A question about Measure, Integration & Real Analysis 2.65 and 2.91
This is the question regarding Luzin's Theorem 1.91. The theorem states that suppose $ g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is a Borel measurable function. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed set $ F \subset \mathbb{R} $ such that $ |\mathbb{R} \setminus F| < \epsilon $ and $ g|_F $ is a continuous function on $ F $.
But consider $ f(x) = 0 $ for $ x $ rational and $ f(x) = 1 $ for $ x $ irrational. Then we cannot find any closed set $ F $ such that $ f $ is continuous at all points of $ F $ and $ |\mathbb{R} \setminus F| < \epsilon $.
I think this is related to Theorem 2.65 in the book which applied in the proof. That theorem states that suppose $ B \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ is a Borel set. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed set $ F \subseteq B $ such that $ |B \setminus F| < \epsilon $.
Similarly, since the set of rational numbers is a Borel set, so is the set of irrational numbers. But let $ B $ be the set of irrational numbers. There exists no closed set $ F $ such that $ |B \setminus F| < \epsilon $.
I'm confused about where my mistake is.

The Wikipedia page on Lusin's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) explains this. There does exist a closed subset of the irrationals where the indicator function is continuous.
